# Convert Local time to epoch time using php

Tags: php, epoch

I need your help please

how can i convert from local time to epoch time

from this: `2016-08-21 12:00`

to this: `1471798800`

i've already tried with this `date('r', $epoch);` but i cant get it
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `$timestamp = strtotime('2016-08-21 12:00');`